# Java Regex captures Group but does not matches()

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match 'MyGroup' from the following string:

```
CN=MyGroup,OU=SomeOU,OU=AnotherOu,DC=SomeDC,DC=AnotherDC,DC=GB
```

Using the following Regex:

```
(?<=CN=).*?(?=,OU=)
```

This captures "MyGroup" however using an online regex tester I get matches() false.
I need to get matches() true for this. I don't have access to the java code, just that it's validating against matches() true.

Comment: `CN=([^,]+),OU=.*`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you so much oh great Regex one. It's working, if you want to answer the question with this response I will mark it as answered and you get some special internet points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
CN=([^,]+),OU=.*
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/04djWg/1).

**Details**

- `CN=` - `CN=` string
- `([^,]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more non-commas
- `,OU=` - a `,OU=` string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.